# no wifi adapter found ubuntu 20.04 Wi-Fi 6 AX201

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

```
root@jira:~/rtw88# sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:c451c000-c451ffff
```

Comment: I suspect that your very new wireless device is not covered in the older Ubuntu version 20.04. Please edit your question to show: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`